# Not able to update data in database form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting error - undefined method `collect` for `nil:NilClass`, but I am able to render option list from another database table, and also able to save data in stage table but not able to update it. 
I am rendering option list form responsibility table in stage form field responsibility option and saves that option into stage table.

[image]

stages_controller.rb

```rb
  def index
    redirect_to project_path(@project)
  end

  def show
  end


  def new
    @stage = Stage.new
    @responsibilities = @project.responsibilities
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
      @responsibilities = @project.responsibilities

    @stage = @project.stages.build(stage_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @stage.save
        format.html { redirect_to project_path(@project), notice: 'Stage was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @stage }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @stage.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def update
    @responsibilities = @project.responsibilities

    respond_to do |format|
      if @stage.update(stage_params)
        format.html { redirect_to project_stages_url, notice: 'Stage was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @stage }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @stage.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @stage.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to project_stages_url, notice: 'Stage was successfully deleted.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_stage
      @stage = Stage.find(params[:id])
    end

    def find_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your edit method is empty, so @responsibility has no content (null), you can put some code for example (from your other method)

```
def edit
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @responsibilities = @project.responsibilities
  ...
end
```

Comment: no need to add  ```@project = Project.find(params[:id]) ``` before action  ```find_project ``` has been set. BTW thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `@responsibilities` is not defined in your partial.

You should pass the local variable to the partial like this -

```
<%= render partial: "form", locals: {responsibilities: @ responsibilities} %>
```

and then you can use `responsibilities` inside the `form partial`

[More about passing variable to partials](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables)